# "Type mismatch" error when calling a simple method in a c# assembly registered for COM interop

Tags: c#, com, interop, type-mismatch

I've build a classlibrary using c# and the .net framework 3.5. In my class library there is a class called Utilities with two methods.

```
public string Method1(int length)
{
}

public string Method2(int length, string aStringParameter)
{
}
```

Now I went and build a simple asp page calling my methods. Method1 work like a charm. Method2 causes a "Type Mismatch" error. What am I missing here?

Comment: how do you call Method2?

Comment: Pls do provide details on how are you invoking the method? Are you invoking the C# assembly as an ActiveX Control ?

Comment: The error was on a stupidity on my side and ASP threw a type mismatch instead of a "Check your syntax, fool" error. What do I do now? Close this question?

Answer (score 1):

Try to put

```
  MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)
```

for string type that you are passing to method2.

[Here](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(VS.71).aspx) is a detailed explanation.